# Django Admin - Adding custom views to model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, view

So basically what I would like is to have a custom view (print view) for one of my model.
I added a custom button and I changed the get_url() of my model:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns('',
        url(r'^/print/schedule$', 
self.admin_site.admin_view(views.PrintScheduleDetailView.as_view()), name='print_schedule'),
    )
    return my_urls + urls
```

When I try to view it:
my_app/my_model/primary_key/print/schedule/
It tells me the object with the pk 1/print/schedule doesn't exist....

What can I do?

Thanks,
Ara

EDIT: Here is my view class:

```
class PrintScheduleDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Tournament
template_name = 'print/schedule.html'
```

I got the link to kinda work...

localhost/tournament/print/schedule/

works but it tells Generic detail view PrintScheduleDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.... I tried adding a primary key localhost/tournament/print/schedule/pk but didnt work...
Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the regular expression should be changed to remove the '^' symbol like:

```
url(r'/print/schedule$'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Detailview of class based views:

> By default this requires `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument
>   in the URLconf, but subclasses can override this to return any object.

```
url(r'^/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/print/schedule/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(views.PrintScheduleDetailView.as_view()), name='print_schedule'),)
```

I believe you need to pass the pk, except if you are fetching it through another way (you haven't pasted your Class View).

Comment: Did you add the url as above? the second try you made clearly states that your pk or slug is missing from the url, you need to specify the position of your pk or slug in the url for the DetailView Class and the Dispatcher to understand where it should look.